# Logout redirection

Tags: php, facebook, logout

Hi im new to the facebook api and have managed to get a user to login using facebook, however I am trying to make a logout that redirects to a different page eg. **logout.php** The issue is when it logs out it redirects to the same page.

The code im using to get the logout link is:

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

How can i make it so the logout url automatically logs you out of facebook and redirects you to logout.php?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

An example of the url i currently get from the **getLogoutUrl()** function:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=*http%3A%2F%2FMYDOMAINHERE.com%2F*&access_token=MYACCESSTOKENHERE

My guess is that if i can pass it a redirection URL to autogenerate with that function it would look something like this:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2FMYDOMAINHERE.com%2F**LOGOUT.PHP**%2F&access_token=MYACCESSTOKENHERE

**UPDATE**

Never mind i just figured it out. Works the same way the login does with the

```
getLogoutUrl(array(
                   'next' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/logout.php'
                   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?:

```
header ("Location: $logoutUrl")
exit;
```

Comment: Just updated the question with a bit more detail i pretty much want to pass a redirection url for the method to generate a logout url with the url i send...